# c++ calling a template functor but not passing an argument

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, functor

I'm trying to understand two things in c++, functors and passing reference. Below is example code for the library `libtins` available here [libtins example](http://libtins.github.io/tutorial/sniffing/). The function `snifferloop()` takes the template functor `doo()`.

The declaration for the functor is `bool doo(PDU &some_pdu)` so the argument `some_pdu` of type `PDU` is passed by reference to the function.

However, `doo()` is called as `sniffer.sniff_loop(doo);` and no argument appears to be passed to `doo()`.

Could somebody explain what is happening here please? Apologies if it is a basic.

```
bool doo(PDU &some_pdu) {
    // Search for it. If there is no IP PDU in the packet, 
    // the loop goes on
    const IP &ip = some_pdu.rfind_pdu<IP>(); // non-const works as well
    std::cout << "Destination address: " << ip->dst_addr() << std::endl;
    // Just one packet please
    return false;
}

void test() {
    SnifferConfiguration config;
    config.set_promisc_mode(true);
    config.set_filter("ip src 192.168.0.100");
    Sniffer sniffer("eth0", config);
    sniffer.sniff_loop(doo);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`sniffer.sniff_loop(doo)` doesn't call `doo`. It calls `sniffer.sniff_loop`, passing a pointer to `doo` as argument to `sniffer.sniff_loop`. Then `sniffer.sniff_loop` will use that argument to call `doo`, passing the argument to `doo`.